# @Input('index') stays zero with ngfor loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

create.component.html

```html
<app-product 
  *ngFor="let product of (products | async); let i = index"  
  [index]="i" 
  [product]="product">
</app-product>
```

product.component.ts

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input('index') index: number;
  constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.index = 0;
    console.log(this.index)
  }
}
```

How comes my index does not gets updated with the input field if i display index in create.component.html i can see ngfor properly gives the value 1 to the input field

Comment: i have put ```app-product``` inside of a div and replaced the ngfor loop to the div so i could output i to the view and saw that it properly incremented to 1 or 2 or 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `index` always to zero (`0`) in `constructor` and prints the value with `console.log` after that assignment. It's clear that it's always zero on your console.

```
this.index = 0;
console.log(this.index)
```

Also the input is not yet set in constructor by Angular. Use the Angular life cycle methods like [OnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) (`ngOnInit`).

Some hints:

- Input name is not recommended / necessary. (Same name as property)
- Set the default value directly on your property declaration.
- In general, use Angular lifecycle events rather than the constructor.

This works (tested):

```html
<app-product
  *ngFor="let product of products | async; let i = index"
  [index]="i"
  [product]="product"
></app-product>
```

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  template: '<div>{{index}} - {{ product | json }}</div>',
})
export class ProductComponent {
  @Input() index = 0;
  @Input() product: unknown;

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    // Expected to be zero. Because input not yet set by Angular.
    console.log(this.index);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Expected to be >= 0. Because you can access the input now. Or use
    console.log(this.index);
    // Here you can also do stuff with this.store.
  }
}
```

Trivia: You could also use [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) to handle every input change.